# Some elements are not showing in openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap, point

I added a point on [openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) several months ago, and that point is not showing in the standard layer (or any other layer).

When I click on the interrogation mark, I can see that the point exist in the database, but no icon is showing for that point :
[image]

If someone can tell me why this is happening (because it is not the first time), I will really appreciate it.

Here are also the point link https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/4541228705 to verify by yourself if you want to.

Comment: This is a question for http://help.openstreetmap.org/. StackOverflow is for *programming* questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all POIs are shown on the standard layer. This can have several reasons:

- The POI is too unimportant to display it.
- The POI hasn't been added to the renderer stylesheet yet.
- The POI is in the stylesheet but not in the renderer database and a re-import of the database would be necessary.

  - The POI is in the stylesheet and the database but there is not enough space to show it.

Your POI is tagged as `office=association`. Currently the `office` key is not rendered on the standard style. There is already a [corresponding [issue for openstreetmap-carto](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/issues/108) (the current default rendering style).

In other words: You did everything right. The reason for the office not being rendered is not your fault. Unfortunately you have to wait until the rendering stylesheet gets updated (you might participate in the mentioned issue to speed things up). Do *not* change the tagging just to make it appear on the map (also called [tagging for the renderer](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tagging_for_the_renderer)). The good news is: Geocoders / routing engines will find your office nevertheless (e.g. [Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Open%20Minds%20Club%2C%20Algeria))! There might even exist other OSM-based maps with a different stylesheet that already show your POI.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for your answer. That issue was created in 2013, so I don't think participating in the issue will help. Do you any OSM based map that can be accessed from the browser and that renders almost anything ??

Comment: You can take a look at the [list of OSM-based services](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM-based_services) but I don't think there is a map that renders anything. I'm pretty confident that the office key will get rendered on the standard OSM layer in the near future.